# How to search DOM elements using XPath or CSS selectors in Chrome Developer Tools?

Tags: dom, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

The doc http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/elements.html says it supports XPath or CSS selectors, but when I tried, didn't seem to work for me.

Any one knows how to use it?

Answer (score 289, accepted):

You can use `$x` in the Chrome javascript console. No extensions needed.

ex: `$x("//img")`

Comment: This is a helpful answer. To add to it, the $x function accepts a second optional argument, context. $x(xpath, context) This allows you to select a particular iframe content, for example, and run an xpath query against it. So for the first iframe: myframe = document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")[0].contentWindow.document.body; #to xpath query that iframe for table cells: $x("//td",myframe);

Comment: to find an element with a CSS selector a one should use $$ console function, e.g. $$('body')

Comment: More commands can be found here: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#selector

Comment: coming back to this question after almost 2 years, yeah this one is nicer.

Comment: Very good for debugging XPaths! By the way, the `$x()` function works in the Safari command line API, too.

Comment: Excellent! I was looking for a way to do it in the elements pane, but this is much easier

Comment: Works with [Firefox Developer Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Helpers) as well

Comment: @billynoah It's a common pattern now, should work in most browsers' dev tools.

Answer (score 16):

Just typing xpath expression in the search box should work. It works for me in tip-of-tree build.

The feature seems to be broken in Chrome 11 though, I've filed a bug on this: http://crbug.com/79716

Comment: you are right. it is working but the highlighting feature is broken. I'm using chrome 10.0.* on Mac os X.

Comment: better answer by Mark Polito below.

Comment: It works with Chrome 32. Go to Element tab of the devtool and press CTRL+S and search for the xpath

Comment: @eeezyy you mean ctrl + f ?

Answer (score 9):

For xpath searches use `$x('xpathSelector')`.
For a css selector use `$('cssSelector')`.

However, this last selector returns only the first matching element. If you want to see all matching elements go for `$$('cssSelector')`

Answer (score 3):

If you click on any element in the elements pane then type command-F, it will open a search bar that lets you search for elements using xpath selectors.

Comment: Or Ctrl-F on Windows